# How can we move customise civicrm from development mode to production?

Tags: deployment

I want to move the customize civicrm from development to production.
But the problem is that if it goes in production then how can I customize again?

Comment: you probably need to explain what you mean by 'customize' - do you mean that you added some Custom Fields, or Activity Types, or that you hacked core, or something else?

Comment: Yes I added some custom field.

Comment: Do you have a Production version already or is this for the initial deployment? in terms of 'how do i customise again' and eg if you mean creating Custom Fields, Tags etc, then best is to create on both systems to ensure you keep all your ids in synch

Comment: should I create a custom field or create a extension?

Comment: I can't answer that - i really don't understand what your situation is and what you need to achieve.

Comment: I want to add some questions and answers( 4 options for one questions). can I create a extension on can I use custom field for that ? If you have a good documentation please send me ( regarding extension .

Comment: if you are taking about a single custom field with four options for the answer, i would just do as a custom field on both Prod and Dev - keep them in synch manually

Comment: I am creating a extension.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you did your customizations in an extension you would install the extension on production. If you then want continue updating your customizations in your extension you can do so on test, and then issue a new release of your extension.

The Upgrader (check https://docs.civicrm.org/dev/en/latest/extensions/civix/#generate-upgrader) can help you to manage what needs to happen on a new installation.